# How to get to a yuimenu object after it's been created?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, yui, yui-menu

I'm got some yuimenu-based popup menus working, and, generally speaking, all is well.  However, I've found that I need to get my hands on a menu object so I can do things to it after it's been created (e.g., hide an exposed menu when something else happens on the page).  I can find the div of class yuimenu, but I need the object so I can (presumably) do a `cfg.setProperty('visibility', 'hidden')` or something similar on it.

So: How can I get this object?  I've tried `YAHOO.widget.Menu(theDivID)`, but that went down in flames.  Thanks!  (ps: If I'm going about this all wrong, please let me know!)

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out a way to do this, but I can't say I'm very pleased with it:

- Declare `allTheMenus,` a global javascript variable meant to collect all the yuimenu items that will be placed on the page.
- When the page is built, push each menu instance onto this variable/array.
- When the Special Event occurs (in my case, the user clicking on a link that brings up an overlay dialog div to collect some user input), do the following:

  - Check the page to see if there are any items of class yuimenu whose style is visible (e.g,. `$('.yuimenu[style*=visible]')...`
  - If there is one (in my case, there can be only one; your situation may vary), get its ID and (ugh) loop through the global array of all yuimenu instances and find the one that has the same ID.
  - Do `this.cfg.setProperty('visible', false)` on it and bail out of the loop (again, assuming there is only one item that might be visible).

Like I said -- I'm not proud of the code, but it's working.  I would LOVE for someone to show me that there's a better way to do it...